# How to pass parameters dynamically in Crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I need to know how to pass the parameter dynamically in crystal report

```
 Dim paramField31 As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField()
 Dim discreteVal1 As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue()
 discreteVal1 = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
 paramField31.ParameterFieldName = "sample"
 discreteVal1.Value = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(2).Item(0))
 paramField31.CurrentValues.Add(discreteVal1)
 paramFields3.Add(paramField31)
```

Comment: What you mean _"pass the parameter during runtime dynamically"_?? And where is the source of parameter?

Comment: This is the best answer link for the above problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279270/how-do-i-load-images-dynamically-in-crystal-reports-xi